# laravel send variable to login route

Tags: laravel

I am using a different app.blade.php than the one provided with the default auth system in laravel. In the one I have created, I need to give a variable each time so that it show where we are in the code. For example, for my routes, I use:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function () {
    $position = ['main_title'=>'Home','second_title'=>'',
                 'urls'=>
                    [
                        ['name'=>'home','url'=>'#']
                    ]
                ];
    return view('home')->with('position',$position);
}]);
```

And in my app.blade.php, I can use this $position to print the main title etc.

Now the problem comes when I try to access login because $position is not set. How can I achieve that in Laravel so that the auth system will use my new blade system?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? separate blade means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auth views use the layout file `app.blade.php` located in `resources/views/layouts`. This is done by the code `@extends('layouts.app')` at top of all the views, which means that the auth views extend this layout.

To change the layout in all the auth views, manually replace the `@extends('layouts.app')` part at top with the new layout file you have created. For example if your new custom layout file is `resources/views/base.blade.php`, then replace the default extends to `@extends('base')`.

Comment: I know that, I was just wondering, when I see the routes for example for the login, there is App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm and I guess from there, it will call the view login form. I was wondering if it was possible to set the variable $position before calling the view?

Comment: @Richard You can. Looks like you're using an older version of laravel based on the controller. The default auth controller uses traits which contains most of the controller logic. So all you have to do is override the method by adding `public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }` in `AuthController`. Now you have full control and can add any additional variables along with the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable in different (all) views, you may use [ViewComposer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers)